# Websocket client cannot send after handshake unless another message is received

Tags: c#, google-chrome, websocket, windows-xp

I have been working on a C# Websocket Server for some time now and there has been one issue that I have worked around but never resolved or found a proper reason for its existence.

My environments that I have tested have been using Google's Chrome browser over the series of versions over the past year or so on Windows XP and Windows 7. My server has been tested on both OS as well.

The problem I notice only occurs when the browser is running under Windows XP. Upon completion of the Websocket Handshake, the browser/client cannot send data to the server unless a message is sent from the server to the client first.

What I have done, is simply tagged on a Ping frame to the end of the server Handshake and all functions as expected. I have tested with other frames as well, so long as the server sends a message, the client will proceed as normal.

The message from the server does not need to be instant either. If the client attempts to send a message, it can wait indefinitely. As soon as the server sends a message to the client, the client proceeds.

Now, I figured I was doing something incorrectly on my Websocket Server, but if this was the case, then why does everything work as expected when the browser is running under Windows 7. I do not need to send a message to the client before the client will release a message to the server.

As a very basic example, here is server code that will never complete if Chrome connects from an XP machine;

```
byte[] textPound = {0x81, 0x01, 0x23};

Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 56100);
server.Bind(ip);
server.Listen(100);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];

Socket client = server.Accept();
int rec = client.Receive(buffer);
Handshake(buffer, ref rec);//custom function returns the handshake to the buffer
client.Send(buffer, rec, SocketFlags.None);

//client.Send(textPound);
rec = client.Receive(b);
client.Close();
```

So long as the .Send() is commented out .Receive() will never complete if Chrome is ran from an XP machine, no matter how you send a message from the browser. If you were to start a thread before .Receive() that would issue a .Send() after x amount of time, the process completes once that happens.

Has anyone experienced this, or know why this may be?

**EDIT** -- For those who do not know what the WebSocket Protocol is;

[Protocol Documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)

[API Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-websockets-20110419/)

Comment: This is not HTTP.  Why are you using a browser to test this?

Comment: The server uses the WebSocket protocol to communicate to a webpage, the webpage is viewed by a browser. In this scenario, depending the platform the browser is on yields different results, I'm seeing if anyone knows why?
In short, the problem depends on the client, the browser is the client, how do I not use a browser to test this?

Comment: A browser deals with Hypertext Transfer Protocol.  The server you have posted above does not communicate using HTTP so a browser should not be expected to behave like the client for whatever protocol you have invented.

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing a new WebSocket implementation, you might have a look at [AutobahnTestsuite](http://www.autobahn.ws/testsuite).

AutobahnTestsuite provides a fully automated test suite to verify client and server implementations of The WebSocket Protocol for specification conformance and implementation robustness.

It's used by dozens of projects and is some kind of "defacto standard" for testing.

Disclosure: I am original author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.